# How can I get a voice confirmation of an alarm?

Tags: alarm

When using the voice search and speaking "set alarm for 10 am", the only audio I get back is "setting alarm...".

While the screen displays a helpful "This alarm is set for 3 hours from now", I'd like to get a similar audio feedback. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

While this may be extremely helpful, I believe that the only way to get this functionality would be to modify the Google Now app, or build the additional response into a custom ROM using one of the TTS modules.

While it is by no means an optimal solution, you could try third-party voice action apps like [Vlingo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vlingo.client&feature=search_result) or [Jeannie](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pannous.voice.actions.free&feature=search_result) to see if they include this functionality.